# Regex to specifically match @first.last format and nothing before or after

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in the format `some words @first.last more words @first.last`. I want to write a regex to pick out any substring in the format `@first.last` so that I can replace that substring with something else. This regex should only consider the `@first.last` substring and ignore any characters preceding the `@` symbol or anything after the first space after `last` including that space.  Ex:

```
regex = new RegExp(/[^\[\s](@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)/im);
str = 'Hey @first.last tell [@first.last] to check this out';
str = str.replace(regex, 'Keanu');
/** str: 'Hey Keanu tell [@first.last] to check this out? **?
```

Regexs I have tried:

- `(@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)` -> Will get me part of the way there but doesn't get rid of characters before `@` symbol
- `[^\[](@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)` -> This regex fails if `@first.last` is the first substring of the string ie. `@first.last look at this` would not be changed by a str.replace call
- `[^\[\s](@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)` -> to try and filter out leading spaces
- `[^.+?](@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)`

The main thing tripping me up is what to include before the `(@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)` to make sure that I only detect the `@` symbol and the characters that immediately follow it in the first.last format.

I appreciate any help and assistance.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(^|\s)@\w+\.\w+(?!\S)`  https://regex101.com/r/Vx9Ivz/1

Comment: The first pattern you listed works fine https://regex101.com/r/jEWY6W/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a character class like `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+` is a bit of a broad match as it does not guarantee for example that the dot is not at the end. It can match any of the listed, so for example `--.--` is also valid. Note that you don't have to escape the dot and also not the dash if it is at the end.

1. The [first pattern](https://regex101.com/r/gVh7EN/1) `(@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)` matches both because there are no boundaries set on the left and the right.
2. The [second pattern](https://regex101.com/r/gVh7EN/2) `[^\[](@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)` matches including the leading space as that is matched by the negated character class `[^\[]` which matches not a `[`
3. The [third pattern](https://regex101.com/r/gVh7EN/3) `[^\[\s](@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)`  does not match because now the negated character class `[^\[\s]` does not allow to match the leading space.
4. The [fourth pattern](https://regex101.com/r/gVh7EN/4) `[^.+?](@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)` matches the leading `[` because that is matched by `[^.+?]` which matches not a `.`, `+` or `?`

You could use a capturing group where the group can match either the start of the string or a whitespace char followed by matching the @ part with word chars and a dot:

```
(^|\s)@\w+\.\w+(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(^|\s)` Capturing group 1, start of string or whitespace char
- `@\w+\.\w+` Match `@`, then 1+ word chars, a dot and 1+ word chars (instead of `\w` you could also use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
- `(?!\S)` Assert that what is directly on the right is not a non whitespace char

In the replacement use the first capturing group follewed by your replacement `$1Keanu`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vx9Ivz/2)

```js
regex = /(^|\s)@\w+\.\w+(?!\S)/g;
str = 'Hey @first.last tell [@first.last] to check this out';
str = str.replace(regex, "$1Keanu");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. It also taught me about look arounds which I was not previously aware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe this expression might also work here,

```
(\s+|^)(@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-]+)(\s+|$)
```

`\s+` is a just in case for additional spaces and we would simply modify the char class, if we wish so.

```js
const regex = /(\s+|^)(@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-]+)(\s+|$)/gis;
const str = `some words @first.last more words @first.last
some words @first.last more words @first.last012 some other text
some words @first.last more words @first.last012\$%^&
some words@first.last more words@first.last`;
const subst = `$1Keanu$3`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### [Please see the demo for explanation and more info.](https://regex101.com/r/NIsPra/1)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Those visualizations are probably not terribly helpful for people that can already write (basic) regex like that.